# Heat Maps in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, heat-map

I have a set of points(lat, lon and other attributes) stored as an Asset in Google Earth Engine. I import this asset as a Feature Collection and visualize the points over Satellite Imagery in Google Earth Engine. I would like to generate a heat map from these points.

I searched extensively over the web, but could not find any resource elaborating on doing this in Google Earth Engine. I did come across this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap of the Google Maps JS API that uses |google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer|.

Is there an equivalent of this in Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 3):

There is not a heatmap function that I know of in Earth Engine but you can create your own using some neighborhood operations that are available in EE. Here is an example:

```
// 'fc' is the feature collection of points
var points = fc.map(function(feature){
  return feature.set('dummy',1);
});

function heatmap(fc,radius){
  var ptImg = points.reduceToImage(['dummy'],ee.Reducer.first()).unmask(0);
  var kernel = ee.Kernel.circle(radius);
  var result = ptImg.convolve(kernel);
  return result.updateMask(result.neq(0));
}

var heatmapImg = heatmap(points,20);

var gradient = ['lightgreen','yellow','red'];

Map.addLayer(heatmapImg,{palette:gradient,min:0,max:0.02},'Heatmap');
```

And here is the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8898e0d0f403b65f50b885676e526807). I hope this helps!

Comment: That is actually a nice approach.

Comment: You can add a bit of smoothing with a gaussian kernel too. e.g. `var kernel = ee.Kernel.circle(radius).add(ee.Kernel.gaussian(radius * 2, radius/2))`